# Emoji support in imagick

Tags: imagick

I want to print the captions imported from facebook/instagram in an image and save it. I want to do this using imagick library with php as I am creating the base image using imagick. The normal text prints properly but the emojis that are imported do not get printed as emoji's. Can anyone suggest how emojis can be printed using imagick.

What I have tried:

```
$eachpageimg = new Imagick ();
$eachpageimg->setResolution ( 300 , 300 );
$eachpageimg->newImage (1050, 1260 , 'rgb(255,255,255)');
$eachpageimg->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$eachpageimg->setImageFormat ('jpeg');
$eachpageimg->setImageCompressionQuality(100);

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' );
$pixel->setColorValue(Imagick::COLOR_ALPHA, .8);

$draw->setStrokeColor('rgb(0,0,0)');
$draw->setFillColor ('rgb(0,0,0)');

$draw->setFont ("ROBOTO-REGULAR");

$draw->setFontSize (70);
$xpos = 10;
$ypos = 200;
$eachpageimg->annotateImage($draw, $xpos, $ypos, 0, "GshdhðŸ˜šðŸ˜ŽðŸ˜‘ðŸ˜šðŸ¤ ");

$filename = 'saved.jpg';
// SAVE FINAL page image
file_put_contents ($filename, $eachpageimg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font you are using needs to have the emojis in them. This can be checked by just editing a word or web page with that font set.

However:

```
"GshdhðŸ˜šðŸ˜ŽðŸ˜‘ðŸ˜šðŸ¤ "
```

Those look very much like a mucked up character set rather than emoji. I strongly suspect that you are saving some data in a character set that doesn't support emoji (i.e. most non-UTF) character sets.

Exactly where that has happened will need to be something you discover yourself.

Comment: Thanks Danack. Now i am getting the text in the correct format as "yummy cake\uD83C\uDF82\uD83C\uDF70". The smileys are also printed. But the smileys are printed in black & white. How can I get coloured smileys. I tried running it on linux as well after installing Apple Color Emoji.ttf font.

Comment: set the stroke and fill color? but also ask it as a separate question if it's an actual problem. And don't forget to upvote + accept...